# Double variable assignment when implementing a validation rules

Tags: python, validation, xlrd

Could someone explain why I have to enter my "name" two times ? Also, if you have a tip. I want the user entering a name once again if loop doesn't find any matches.

```
import xlrd

def open_file(path):
    wb = xlrd.open_workbook(path)
    sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)

    while True:
        name = input("name: ")
        nbre_consulate = 1

        for row_num in range(sheet.nrows):
            row_value = sheet.row_values(row_num)

            if row_value[0] == name and row_value[1] == nbre_consulate:
                return int(row_value[2])

path = "imperator.xlsx"
open_file(path)

print(open_file(path))
```

I have to write two times the "name" before having my `row_value[3]`. I can't get why.

```
name: Spurius Lartius
name: Spurius Lartius
506
```

Thanks for any tips !

Comment: For the tip you are looking for, what is the current behaviour when the user enters a name that isn't found?

Comment: Look closely at how many times you *call* the function, and how many times you display the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to enter your name twice because you run the entire function twice. Do you see where you run the function and then do the same thing with the print statement? The value you're seeing is not only printed but generated by where you are running your function in a print statement. What you can do to fix it is assign it to a variable when you run it and then print the variable separately like so:

```
path = "imperator.xlsx"
row_value_3 = open_file(path)

print(row_value_3)
```

Comment: Perfect answer I totally get it. Thanks